# Why BitVector 32 structure is more efficient than BitArray?

Tags: c#, collections, bitvector

What is the  difference between BitArray and BitVector 32 structure and what are the advantages of BitVector 32 structure over BitArray? Why is the BitVector 32 structure more efficient than BitArray?

Thanks in advance.

Jay...

Answer (score 17):

> BitVector32 is more efficient than BitArray for Boolean values and small integers that are used internally. A BitArray can grow indefinitely as needed, but it has the memory and performance overhead that a class instance requires. In contrast, a BitVector32 uses only 32 bits.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32.aspx

BitVector32 is a struct and consumes only 4 bytes. BitArray is a class that has overheads associated with it and is therefore less efficient - BitArray will need at least 8 bytes before you've even added any objects to it as it lives on the heap. [More about the stack and heap here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477101/heap-versus-stack-allocation-implications-net).

Answer (score 9):

Here is what [Microsoft's documentation for BitVector32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32.aspx) states:

> `BitVector32` is more efficient than `BitArray` for Boolean values and small integers that are used internally. A `BitArray` can grow indefinitely as needed, but it has the memory and performance overhead that a class instance requires. In contrast, a `BitVector32` uses only 32 bits.

The capacity of `BitVector32` is limited to 32 bits, the size of an `int`. Therefore, indexing and masking can be single operations. Compare this to a bit array with 734 bits and you want to find out if bit 197 is set. Think about how you would do that (from the perspective of the class designer).

Comment: But in BitVector32 also we create an intance of that type.

 BitVector32 newVector = new BitVector32(4); //like this.

Comment: @Jaywith.7 » A new instance of a struct doesn't have the same overhead as an instance of a class.

Answer (score 4):

A [`BitVector32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32.aspx) gets it boost over [`BitArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) because it is just a 32 bit integer and does not have the overhead associated with a class (mainly the memory overhead).

This means if you need to store more then 32 Boolean values then you will either need to use `BitArray` or multiple `BitVector32`.  Since multiple `BitVector32` might be cumbersum you might want to put them into an array or a class, which would remove the performance boost.

In short, if you need to store 32 or less Boolean values then use a `BitVector32`.  If you need to store more then evaluate your needs and coding conditions before blindly picking `BitVector32`, otherwise you might make more work for yourself reinventing `BitArray` and not see any of the performance benefits.

Note: in most cases I prefer using a [flagged enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.flagsattribute.aspx) instead of a `BitVectore32`.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/enum-flags-attribute) for an explanation and some good tricks.